# Azure Java SDK: ServiceException: ForbiddenError:

Tags: java, azure, keystore, azure-java-sdk

Tried the basic location retriever code (shown below)

```
String uri = "https://management.core.windows.net/";
        String subscriptionId = "XXXXXXXX-5fad-XXXXXX-9dfa-XXXXXX";
         String keyStoreLocation = "D:\\test.jks";
         String keyStorePassword = "123456";

        Configuration config = ManagementConfiguration.configure(
                  new URI(uri), 
                  subscriptionId,
                  keyStoreLocation, // the file path to the JKS
                  keyStorePassword, // the password for the JKS
                  KeyStoreType.jks // flags that I'm using a JKS keystore
                ); 


        ManagementClient client = ManagementService.create(config);
        // get the list of regions
        LocationsListResponse response = client.getLocationsOperations().list();
        ArrayList<Location> locations = response.getLocations();
        // write them out
        for( int i=0; i<locations.size(); i++){
          System.out.println(locations.get(i).getDisplayName());

    }
```

and It works fine. But when I try to create the ComputeManagementClient and try to restart a VM

```
ComputeManagementClient computeManagementClient = ComputeManagementService.create(config);
        VirtualMachineOperations virtualMachinesOperations= computeManagementClient.getVirtualMachinesOperations();
virtualMachinesOperations.restart("SQLVM", "sqlvm.cloudapp.net");
```

I'm getting the certificate error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.microsoft.windowsazure.exception.ServiceException: ForbiddenError: The server failed to authenticate the request. Verify that the certificate is valid and is associated with this subscription.
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
    at com.microsoft.azure.management.compute.VirtualMachineOperationsImpl.restart(VirtualMachineOperationsImpl.java:9973)
    at com.microsoft.azure.compute.RestartVMExample.main(RestartVMExample.java:84)
```

PS: I created a the .cer from Java Keystore and uploaded into Azure with no issues.

Any clues what is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by using the incorrect Azure Java SDK libraries.
When I used the maven dependencies in the file pom.xml below, I reproduced the same exception.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
   <artifactId>azure-mgmt-compute</artifactId>
   <version>0.8.3</version>
</dependency>
```

The library  supply the VM restart function need two arguments: `resource group name` and `vm name`. But the API of library `azure-mgmt-compute` is used for Azure Resource Management.

To restart VM, you need to use the API of library `azure-svc-mgmt-compute` for Azure Service Management if you used JKS certificates. The Class `VirtualMachineOperations` supply the same name function `restart` need three arguments: `service name`, `deployment name` and `vm name`. You can find these names from Cloud Service dashboard on Azure Portal. In your issue code, the `vm name` should be "sqlvm".

The right maven pom.xml for dependencies as below:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
   <artifactId>azure-svc-mgmt</artifactId>
   <version>0.8.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
   <artifactId>azure-svc-mgmt-compute</artifactId>
   <version>0.8.3</version>
</dependency>
```

And the code as below

```
virtualMachinesOperations.restart("<service name: sqlvm>", "<deployment name: sqlvm>", "<vm name: sqlvm>");
```

---

The steps below for genkeypair by using Java Keytool in the path JAVA_HOME/bin:

```
keytool -genkeypair -alias keyfile -keyalg RSA -keystore <KeyStore.jks> 
-keysize 2048 -storepass "<password>"

keytool -v -export -file <KeyStore.cer> -keystore KeyStore.jks -alias keyfile
```

My code:

```
String uri = "https://management.core.windows.net/";
String subscriptionId = "<subscription_id>";
String keyStoreLocation = "KeyStore.jks";
String keyStorePassword = "<password>";

Configuration config = ManagementConfiguration.configure(
       new URI(uri), 
       subscriptionId,
       keyStoreLocation, // the file path to the JKS
       keyStorePassword, // the password for the JKS
       KeyStoreType.jks // flags that I'm using a JKS keystore
    ); 
ComputeManagementClient computeManagementClient = ComputeManagementService.create(config);
VirtualMachineOperations virtualMachinesOperations = computeManagementClient.getVirtualMachinesOperations();
virtualMachinesOperations.restart("petercore", "petercore", "petercore");
```

Comment: are you sure that the restart function has 3 arguments? I still get 2 argument even after the mentioned dependencies. :(

Comment: @HarishRaj The complete package Class name is `com.microsoft.windowsazure.management.compute.VirtualMachineOperations`, not `com.microsoft.azure.management.compute.VirtualMachineOperations`. Please refer to http://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/com/microsoft/windowsazure/management/compute/VirtualMachineOperations.html

Comment: Thanks, Peter. But after changing the package, I got this error - Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.microsoft.windowsazure.exception.ServiceException: AuthenticationFailed: The JWT token does not contain expected audience uri 'https://management.core.windows.net/' :(

Comment: with the .jks file, I got this: [Fatal Error] :1:50: White spaces are required between publicId and systemId.

Comment: @HarishRaj My code is the same as yours. I think you need to check the KeyStore Configuration.

Comment: Did you try using Service Principal Auth with the same code and did it work?

Comment: @HarishRaj This is the Service Principal Auth. For the Azure Service Manegement, there are two ways to auth the management secure: Azure AD & Management Certificate. You can refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460782.aspx. If you don't want to generate a new cert file and upload it into Azure, you can use Azure-CLI to run the command `azure account cert export` to export the named <subscriptionId>.cert file. And refer to http://alvinalexander.com/java/java-using-keytool-import-certificate-keystore to import the certificate into a keyStore file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92125/discussion-between-harish-raj-and-peter-pan-msft).

Comment: @HarishRaj Your issue code for Azure Resource Management must be authenticated with Azure AD. Please refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn790557.aspx to do it.