# Azure getting operation status based on request id java sdk

Tags: java, azure, azure-resource-manager

In Azure resource group java API, there is no function to get the operation status based on a request ID. What is the way to get the operation status in the sdk now ?

Similar functionality exists in the service management API like here for the service management client :
http://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/com/microsoft/windowsazure/management/compute/ComputeManagementClient.html#getOperationStatus-java.lang.String-

Similar function does not exist in the clients like :
http://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/com/microsoft/azure/management/compute/VirtualMachineOperations.html

I see a similar function :

> LongRunningOperationResponse  getLongRunningOperationStatus(java.lang.String
>   operationStatusLink)

The Get Operation Status operation returns the status of the specified operation.

How to generate the operationStatusLink ?

Answer (score 1):

I checked the Azure Reference document, and I found that the reference of `Asynchronous Request (classic) REST` has the `Get Operation Status` REST API what require `<subscription-id>`, `<request-id>` and request header`x-ms-version` for Service Management. Please refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460783.aspx.

Then, I reviewed the JavaDocs of Azure SDK and found the Class `com.microsoft.windowsazure.core.OperationStatusResponse` and `com.microsoft.windowsazure.core.AzureAsyncOperationResponse`. They have the function `getStatus()` what return the one of the Enum `com.microsoft.windowsazure.core.OperationStatus`.
 For their details, please refer to http://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/com/microsoft/windowsazure/core/OperationStatusResponse.html and  http://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/com/microsoft/azure/management/network/models/AzureAsyncOperationResponse.html and http://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/com/microsoft/windowsazure/core/OperationStatus.html.

They are for Azure Service Management. So you need to import these Classes from the maven repo `azure-svc-mgmt` http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/azure-svc-mgmt/0.9.0, see the maven configure below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-svc-mgmt</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And using the function `OperationStatusResponse getOperationStatus(String requestId)` of the Class `com.microsoft.windowsazure.management.ManagementClient` to get the Object `OperationStatusResponse` to get your wants. Please refer to http://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/com/microsoft/windowsazure/management/ManagementClient.html.

Best Regards.

Comment: I am using resource manager based API. The authentication that I doing is based on the application created in the AD. In this case when I try to use the service SDK like you suggested above, I am getting the following error, I am using the same configuration object : SEVERE: null
com.microsoft.windowsazure.exception.ServiceException: ForbiddenError: The server failed to authenticate the request. Verify that the certificate is valid and is associated with this subscription.
 at com.microsoft.windowsazure.exception.ServiceException.createFromXml(ServiceException.java:208)
 at

Comment: @Squid There are two authenticate methods for Service Management: using AAD and using a management certificate(recommended), please refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460782.aspx. These threads I had answered can help you resolve the issue.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33082328/azure-java-sdk-serviceexception-forbiddenerror, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33127506/azure-retrieving-the-publicipaddress-of-virtualmachines-from-azure-java-sdk and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33239530/azure-free-trial-account-not-able-to-authenticate-via-java-sdk.