# MS Azure Java client code throws the error

Tags: java, azure

I try to code MS Azure Java client code like below,

```
Configuration config = ManagementConfiguration.configure(
          new URI(uri), 
          subscriptionId, 
          keyStoreLocation,
          keyStorePassword,
         KeyStoreType.jks
       );
   
   ManagementClient mclient = ManagementService.create(config);
   
   System.out.println("Azure URI Path : " + mclient.getBaseUri()); 
   System.out.println("Azure API Version : " + mclient.getApiVersion());
   System.out.println("Azure의 Publishing ID : " + mclient.getCredentials().getSubscriptionId());
   
   LocationsListResponse lresp = mclient.getLocationsOperations().list(); **// this line throws error**
   ArrayList<Location> locations = lresp.getLocations();
   System.out.println("Azure Regions : ");
   for( int i=0; i<locations.size(); i++){
    System.out.println("\t" + locations.get(i).getName());
   }
```

The following error is throws

```
Azure URI path : https://azure.microsoft.com/
Azure API verion : 2014-10-01
Azure publishing ID : 92a65f9e-b6b6-4eaa-b5f7-e3180db19b62


    [Fatal Error] :1:747: element type "n.length" next attribute ">" 또는 "/>"가 와야 합니다.
    Exception in thread "main" com.microsoft.windowsazure.exception.ServiceException:  <html> <head><script type="text/javascript">window.NREUM||(NREUM={});NREUM.info = {"beacon":"bam.nr-data.net","errorBeacon":"bam.nr-data.net","licenseKey":"b39980acba","applicationID":"10503464,11287305","transactionName":"Y1VSYkBRWEIEWhcICVoffWBxH2VYEVwgDghAQl9aXlVEHjVYBAQ=","queueTime":0,"applicationTime":29,"ttGuid":"7E0843DBD8B8C0A","agent":""}</script><script type="text/javascript> <style>
             body {
                 background-color: #1a1a1a;
             }
    
            .tutorial-icon svg use {
                 stroke: #00abec;
             }
         </style> </head> <body> <svg class="svg-definition"><defs><symbol id="azure" viewBox="-1 -1 34 34"><path d="M19,17.4c-0.8,0-1.5,0.5-1.9,1.2H5.3v0c-2,0-3.6-1.6-3.6-3.6s1.6-3.6,3.6-3.6v0h0h0H7
    
     <div class="column medium-9"> <ul class="linkList linkList-horizontal"> <li><a href="Feedbackhttps://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback">Feedback</a></li> <li><a href="Trademarkshttps://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=222682&clcid=0x409">Trademarks</a></li> <li><a href="Privacy">https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248681&clcid=0x409">Privacy &amp; Cookies</a></li> </ul> </div> <div class="column medium-3"> <div class="footer-copyright pull-right"> <a href="https://www.microsoft.com" class="logo-microsoft">Microsoft</a> <span>&copy; 2016 Microsoft</span> </div> </div> </div> </footer> <script type="text/javascript">
             function clearTextInput() {
                 document.getElementById('search-404').reset();
    
    
          .....
         </script> </body> </html>
      at com.microsoft.windowsazure.exception.ServiceException.createFromXml(ServiceException.java:216)
      at com.microsoft.windowsazure.management.LocationOperationsImpl.list(LocationOperationsImpl.java:162)
      at com.aaa.azure.JavaClient.main(JavaClient.java:60)
```

Java SDK is integrated with Eclipse with Build Path.

Any idea?

Comment: I generated jks file with this command,      keytool.exe –importkeystore –srckeystore SampleRemoteAccessPrivate.pfx -destkeystore .\SampleRemoteAccessPrivate.jks -srcstoretype pkcs12 -deststoretype JKS      . But this time the exception is thrown like this, Exception in thread "main" com.microsoft.windowsazure.exception.ServiceException: ForbiddenError: The server failed to authenticate the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the error information, it seems that you used the incorrect uri `https://azure.microsoft.com/` for the `ManagementConfiguration`.

As I know, the URI for authenticating Azure Service Management is `https://management.core.windows.net/`

More details for getting started with Azure Management Libraries for Java, please see the blog https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/getting-started-with-the-azure-java-management-libraries/.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I changes the uri to https://management.core.windows.net/ as you told. But the code throws the following exception : com.microsoft.windowsazure.exception.ServiceException: ForbiddenError: The server failed to authenticate the request. Any idea?

Comment: @JosephHwang Please see my answer for the other SO thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33082328/azure-java-sdk-serviceexception-forbiddenerror. Hope it helps. Any update, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: I think i have to learn how to export my jks file to ms azure could setting. I try to contact to https://management.core.windows.net/ with the jks key file. but the same exception is thrown. And I have 2 msdn accounts. Do you think this can bring the trouble I have? And my another question is my java client source worked well with previous azure portal web. , but this azure portal site the codes does not work...

Comment: I have one more question. I use eclipse ide with azure plugin. so when my azure project is build the key files are generated in the <PROJECT_HOME>\cert folder which names SampleRemoteAccessPublic.cer and SampleRemoteAccessPrivate.pfx. But even with these files I can't connect azure cloud with azure java sdk

Comment: I found the correct answer in Azure classic portal web. It 's 'configuration' menu of azure classic portal. In configuration menu of classic portal I upload public key(.cer) and in java client access is successful with private key(jks). But I don't know which menu of azure portal has the same configuration menu of classic configuration. I need your advice. Thanks!